# How to install Jenkins charm with dependecies?

Tags: juju

I have a question about the jenkins charm:

After creating a new instance with a jenkins charm, how can I run a script with commands to install some programs needed in machine created?

Comment: one question for one post please :)

Answer (score 3):

If you need quick access to the machine you can:

```
juju ssh jenkins/0
```

Assuming 0 is your machine number (you can find out specifically by running `juju status`).

If you're wanting to do this on every machine you spawn, you might want to consider downloading the charm and modifying it to meet your exact deployment needs. This is especially useful if it's things that are useful to you or your organization. You can do this by branching the code:

```
bzr branch lp:charms/jenkins
```

and then deploying from that instead of from the charm store.

If it's something that you feel is useful for the Jenkins-using community in general then I encourage you to consider [contributing](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/charm-store.html#submitting-a-fix-to-an-existing-charm) to the charm.

Comment: Have a way of doing it generic and non-manual? We do not want to directly modify a charm at this time.